# Node JS: How to create custom variables?

Tags: node.js

Is there anyway to create a variable that when you do `console.log(myVar)`, it prints `Hello, World!` and when you do `myVar.foo("Mike")`, it prints `Hello, Mike!`? It would be like `String`. If you print it, you print its string value and if you use its commands, you get an output.

`myVar.foo`'s code:

```js
function(name) {
  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
}
```

Comment: You want `myvar` to be both variable and object with a method `foo` at the same time? Doesn't make much sense to me!

Comment: Yes, I want this. Example: `createInvite` command of `discord.js` returns a variable and if you print you get `https://discord.gg/(invite code)` and if you print its `code` key you get `(invite code)`.

Comment: can you post more lines, what does myVar.foo() do?

Comment: Maybe create a class with a `toString` function. Then instantiate `myVar new MyClass()`.

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom `toString` method and use it like this:

```
function func() {
    this.name = 'World';
}

func.prototype.toString = function() {
    return `Hello ${this.name}!`;
}
func.prototype.foo = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var myVar = new func();

console.log(myVar.toString()); // Hello World!
myVar.foo('Mike');
console.log(myVar.toString()); // Hello Mike!
```

To print in foo method itself, the code of foo needs to change as:

```
func.prototype.foo = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log(this.toString());
}
myVar.foo('Mike'); // Hello Mike!
```

Comment: The question says: when you do `myVar.foo("Mike")`, it prints `Hello, Mike!`. Your answer doesn't do that.

Comment: The question was edited. I've edited my answer accordingly.